# Convert Excel Range to HTML-Table

Tags: html, css, excel

Because I didn't find a proper solution, I developed an own code to convert an excel range into an html table. The result is a string and can be used within a mail for example.

Answer (score 0):

The following code considers: cell dimension, font-family, -style, -size and alignment, border-style and -color (top, right, bottom, left) and interior-color

```
Function convertRangeToHtml(rng As Range) As String
    
    Dim r As Range
    Dim c As Range
    
    Dim strHtml As String
    
    strHtml = "<table style=" & Chr(34) & "border-collapse: collapse;" & Chr(34) & " > " & vbNewLine & "<tbody>"
    
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        strHtml = strHtml & vbTab & "<tr>" & vbNewLine
        For Each c In r.Columns
            strHtml = strHtml & vbTab & vbTab & "<td " & getCellDimension(c) & " style=" & Chr(34) & getFontStyle(c) & " " & getBorder(c) & " " & getInteriorColor(c) & Chr(34) & ">" & Trim(c.Text) & "</td>" & vbNewLine
        Next c
        strHtml = strHtml & vbTab & "</tr>" & vbNewLine
    Next r
    
    strHtml = strHtml & "</table>" & vbNewLine & "</tbody>"
    
    Debug.Print strHtml
    
    convertRangeToHtml = strHtml

End Function

Function getInteriorColor(r As Range) As String

    getInteriorColor = "background-color: rgb(" & color2rgb(r.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color) & "); "

End Function

Function getBorder(r As Range) As String

    Dim varBorderSytle As Variant
    varBorderSytle = "border-style: "
    
    Dim varBorderWidth As Variant
    varBorderWidth = "border-width: "
    
    Dim varBorderColor As Variant
    varBorderColor = "border-color: "
    
    For Each b In Array(8, 10, 9, 7)
        Select Case r.Borders(b).LineStyle
            Case -4115
                varBorderSytle = varBorderSytle & "dashed "
            Case -4142
                varBorderSytle = varBorderSytle & "none "
            Case 1
                varBorderSytle = varBorderSytle & "solid "
            Case -4118
                varBorderSytle = varBorderSytle & "dotted "
            Case Else
                varBorderSytle = varBorderSytle & "solid "
        End Select
        
        Select Case r.Borders(b).Weight
           Case 1
                varBorderWidth = varBorderWidth & "1px "
            Case -4138
                varBorderWidth = varBorderWidth & "2px "
            Case 4
                varBorderWidth = varBorderWidth & "3px "
            Case 2
                varBorderWidth = varBorderWidth & "1px "
            Case Else
                varBorderWidth = varBorderWidth & "1px "
        End Select
        
        varBorderColor = varBorderColor & "rgb(" & color2rgb(r.Borders(b).Color) & ") "
        
    Next b
    varBorderSytle = varBorderSytle & ";"
    varBorderWidth = varBorderWidth & ";"
    varBorderColor = varBorderColor & ";"

    getBorder = varBorderSytle & " " & varBorderWidth & " " & varBorderColor

End Function

Function getCellDimension(r As Range) As String

    getCellDimension = "width=" & Chr(34) & r.Width * 96 / 72 & "" & Chr(34) & " height=" & Chr(34) & r.Height * 96 / 72 & "" & Chr(34)

End Function

Function getFontStyle(r As Range) As String

    Dim varFontColor As Variant
    Dim varFontName As Variant
    Dim varFontStyle As Variant
    Dim varFontSize As Variant
    Dim varFontBold As Variant
    Dim varFontItalic As Variant
    Dim varTextAlign As Variant
    
    varFontColor = "color: rgb(" & color2rgb(r.DisplayFormat.Font.Color) & "); "
    varFontName = "font-family: " & r.Font.Name & "; "
    varFontSize = "font-size: " & r.DisplayFormat.Font.Size & "pt; "

    varFontBold = "font-weight: normal; "
    If r.DisplayFormat.Font.Bold Then varFontBold = "font-weight: bold; "
    
    varFontStyle = "font-style: normal; "
    If r.DisplayFormat.Font.Italic Then varFontStyle = "font-style: italic; "
    
    Select Case r.HorizontalAlignment
        Case -4131
            varTextAlign = "text-align: left; "
        Case -4152
            varTextAlign = "text-align: right; "
        Case -4108
            varTextAlign = "text-align: center; "
        Case -4130
            varTextAlign = "text-align: justify; "
        Case 1
            Select Case Application.Evaluate("TYPE(" & r.Address(0, 0, external:=True) & ")")
                Case 1
                    varTextAlign = "text-align: right; "
                Case 2
                    varTextAlign = "text-align: left; "
                Case 4, 16
                    varTextAlign = "text-align: center; "
                Case Else
                    varTextAlign = "text-align: start; "
            End Select
    End Select
    
    Dim strCSS As String

    strCSS = varFontColor & varFontName & varFontSize & varFontBold & varFontStyle & varTextAlign
    
    getFontStyle = strCSS
    
End Function

Function color2rgb(varColor As Variant) As String

    color2rgb = Format((varColor Mod 256), "00") & ", " & Format(((varColor \ 256) Mod 256), "00") & ", " & Format((varColor \ 65536), "00")

End Function
```

Additionally I would suggest to add a css-style wihtin the final html-file:

```
td {
    padding:1pt 4pt 1pt 4pt;
}
```

Comment: That CSS doesn't seem to be right one? Don't you need to suffix the numbers with `px`?

Comment: I thought so too, but outlook can handle it